# Handling exception - negative square root in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a piece of code to handle the exception of negative square roots, since I only want a positive result. My code is:

```
def sqRoot(x):
    try: 
        result = (x)**0.5
    except ValueError:
        result = "This is a negative root"
    except TypeError:
        result = "Please enter a number"
    return result
```

For some reason, when I run this code using the call

```
x = sqRoot(-200)
```

I don't get the error, but instead python is giving me the result as a complex number. I can't seem to see the error in my code.

Comment: What version of python are you using? When I run `(-200)**0.5` on python 2.7.9 I get a ValueError exception, but on python 3.4.3 the result is a complex number.

Comment: I also ran it on 2.3.2 which I have installed elsewhere and I get the ValueError exception.

Comment: Check out the python documentation for the [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) which explicitly states that in Python 3 the result is a complex number but in earlier versions it raised a ValueError.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Is there another method for me to take the square root? Or to handle the error?

Answer (score 6):

Shifting this discussion from the comments...

In Python 3.0 the behaviour of the [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) changed. In earlier versions of python, raising a negative number to a fractional power raised a ValueError exception, but in Python 3 it yields a complex result.

An alternative for finding the square root is the python is the [math.sqrt](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/math.html#math.sqrt) function. In Python 3 this raises a ValueError exception when used with a negative number:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(-200)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: I used the math.sqrt function, I didn't even think of that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If python 3 returns a complex number and that is not what you want, you can always achieve the desired output with an if statement:

```
def sqRoot(x):
    if not isinstance(x, (int, long, float)):
        return "Please enter a number"
    if x < 0:
        return "This is a negative root"
    return (x)**0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in python 3, the square root of a negative number is defined (as complex), you will have to test for it yourself:

```
def sqRoot(x):
    if not type(x) in [int, long, float]:
        result = "Please enter a number"
    elif x < 0:
        result = "This is a negative root"
    else:
        result = (x)**0.5
    return result
```

By the way, I don't think that it's good programming practice to have the function return numbers in one case, and strings in the other. I think that is better done by raising errors.